# Milia gem Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to install milia gem on Rails 6 but it gives me an error

my gemfile

```
  gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'milia'
```

ApplicationController.rb

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :authenticate_tenant!
 end
```

Command I use for installing
      rails g milia:install --org_email='noreply@example.com'

Error generate

```
  /home/kash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/type.rb:27: 
  warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be 
  added to the call
  /home/kash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activerecord- 
  6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9: warning: The called method 
  `add_modifier' is defined here
  /home/kash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/milia- 
  0.3.30/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `<class:RegistrationsController>': 
  undefined method `skip_before_filter' for Milia::RegistrationsController:Class
  Did you mean?  skip_before_action (NoMethodError)
     from /home/kash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/milia- 
  0.3.30/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `<module:Milia>'
    from /home/kash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/milia-
```

Answer (score 0):

Milia gem is out of the box right now.its deprecate in update rails version